# how to unpack dmoz urls from rdf dump with python and rdflib?

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, dmoz

i tried to open rdf file (dmoz rdf dump), but a get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/_dev_/ODP_RDF_get_links.py", line 4, in <module>
    result = g.parse("data/content.rdf")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/graph.py", line 1033, in parse
    parser.parse(source, self, **args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py", line 577, in parse
    self._parser.parse(source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 352, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py", line 160, in endElementNS
    self.current.end(name, qname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py", line 331, in node_element_end
    self.error("Repeat node-elements inside property elements: %s"%"".join(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib/plugins/parsers/rdfxml.py", line 185, in error
    raise ParserError(info + message)
file:///media/_dev_/data/content.rdf:5:12: Repeat node-elements inside property elements: http://dmoz.org/rdf/catid
```

my simple code is as follow:

```
import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph()
result = g.parse("data/content.rdf")

print("graph has %s statements." % len(g))
```

1. i need to be able to read the file.
2. extract all links in the world category.

thanks for any possible help

**EDIT:**

**PS:** found this [wikipedia rdf_dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMOZ#RDF_dumps), so developing custom scripts is necessary to use this dump

Comment: What's the RDF that you got?  It looks like a parse error, so maybe it's not actually legal RDF.

Comment: if there is another way, that will be great

Comment: maybe that's true,it's content.rdf.u8.gz file from rdf.dmoz.org/rdf but this file is the only way to get links from ODP !